# ERROR: Cannot find module. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry. Create react app error

Tags: reactjs

This error is popping up when I am trying to create the react app. I am running the command
npx create-react-app my-app. I have created few react apps and no problem as such faced.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM9Z5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to removing your `node_modules` and reinstalling. You can do so with:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

Comment: Your solution does not works. Its showing "'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".